# 90s (or earlier) mecha anime: dormant robot chooses a teenager as its pilot, they fight a dog robot and an ostrich robot

Tags: story-identification, anime

There’s an anime I’ve been looking for the past 18 years. 
The anime was about a young boy that stumbles upon a giant white robot that’s been dormant for some years. When the robot senses the boy, it awakens and chooses him as its pilot. To access the robot he uses some sort of scroll. During the series the giant white robot fights two guardian-like robots… One is a blue dog and the other is a bird or something.

In the first episode, the boy was running.  He slipped and fell in the ground.  Then he sees the giant white robot underground.  It's attached to wires and some says it has been dormant for many years.  The robot senses the boy and awakens.  The boy's grandfather gave him a scroll or baton which allows him to access the robot.  Along the way he battles other robots, one of them a dog and bird that are guardians who fuse together.

The boy must have been around 15 years old... he was Japanese.  The robot was alien similar to a Gundam.  The scroll was silver with holes in it.  The dog was blue and silver.  The bird was yellow, looked like an ostrich. I don't know why they fought but it was for good.  He did leave the mecha now and again.

I’ve asked fellow anime viewers and they can’t figure it out.

Comment: I assume [this](http://www.fortressofsolitude.co.za/classic-cartoons/) is you as well. I find it difficult to believe you've not remembered any additional details in over a year of searching online

Comment: You've also mentioned more details in that post than you've put here (for example which TV Network you saw it on).

Comment: lol i watched this anime when i was 6 or 7.

Comment: I never mention the network which is SABC 2 because i'm from south africa...wasn't really sure it would help

Comment: If you work through the checklists [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) you might come up with some more details for us

Comment: How young was the boy? What race was the boy? Was the robot alien or human? Why was it dormant? What was the scroll? What did it do? How big was the mecha? Were the dog and the bird the same size? Why did they fight it? Did he spend the whole time in the mecha or did he ever leave it? Did the boy have any friends? Was there a love-interest? Do you remember the boy's name? Was the robot called anything?

Comment: What style of animation was it, Japanese anime or Western?

Comment: it was japanese animation style

Comment: http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Lagann - Far too late, but a very similar premise

Comment: I watched tengen toppa gurren lagann lol

Answer (score 6):

That sounds quite a bit like [*Zoids: Chaotic Century*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoids:_Chaotic_Century). The first part sounds almost identical to it.

This is an anime from the very late '90s to '04 and aired on Cartoon Network and other cartoon networks around the world during this time. The very first episode opens with a boy fleeing across the desert where he comes upon a ruin where he finds said white robot in a pod. Inside the pod, and around it, the robot is covered and connected to wires and tubes that it bursts free of when it senses the boy.

There is a blue robotic dog/wolf Zoid later on, and the main antagonist uses a small black robot with wings and later a larger dinosaur/bird-like robot.

Other details don't match up but it was shown alongside *Gundam* and *Transformers* so it's entirely possible some details are bleeding together. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It could also be [*Soul Frame Lazenca*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/28201/Yeonghongibyeong_Lazenca) (1997).

> In the beginning of the 22nd Century, nuclear war has devastated the Earth and turned it into a wasteland. The few survivors gather and raise the city-state Setos, and while progressing a revival plan for mankind, come into contact with the Atman lifeforms sleeping in the planet's mantle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  It would be great to get an answer for this question, but you could improve your answer by noting the specific elements of this that match the details of the question.  (Just linking to the video isn't ideal because it may disappear someday.)  Does the boy appear?  Does he battle dog and bird robots?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds a lot like Reideen! teenage boy daily day gets disrupted and gets called to the robot thing [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F! You could improve your answer by noting the specific elements of this that match the details of the question. A summary of [Reideen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reideen#Overview) suggests he uses a control bracelet, not a scroll (as pictured), so you should highlight ways this _does_ match. Does he battle dog and bird robots?